# Create a view that exists even if session ends in Redshift?

Tags: view, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view in Redshift.But when I close the session and again reopen it then given view is not present.How can I create a view that exists even if my session expires?

Comment: please make sure you are "commiting" after creating the view.

Comment: My bad ,I forgot to commit.It is working fine by commiting the changes.Thanks Jon Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not session dependent. They'll exist in storage like any other table.

Are you prefixing your `create view []` statement with a schema name i.e. `create view schemaname.viewname`? If not, the view will either get created in your public schema or the default schema search path.

A way to troubleshoot is to go through the different schema listed and then find out where your view has been created.

1. If you find your view in `public` schema, you'll get to know that if no default search path is set and schemaname is not mentioned while creating tables/views, it gets created in the public schema by default.
2. If you find your view in any other schema, you'll get to know what your search path is.

Answer (score 0):

Views are persistent.

Some possible reasons why you can't see the view:

- You are connecting as a different user who has a different Schema search path
- You are connecting to a different database
- You created the view in a different schema and when you reconnected you went to a default schema

Answer (score 0):

Adding to previous answers, the view dependencies (tables that are used in the view definition) might be dropped and view is dropped consequently.